# Delete properties from Jobject c#

Tags: c#, json

Im new to Json and i I want to filter unneeded information from my JObject.
I have a JObject as follow:

```
 {
    "A": "sr",
    "B": {
      "B1": "some data",
      "B2": "some data,
      "Values": [
        {
          "C1": "some info",
          "C2": someinfo",
          "C3": {
            "D1": "some info",
            "D2": [
              "cat",
              "dog",
              "fish"
            ],
            "D3": "some info"
          },
          "C4": "some info",
          "C5": "some info"
        },
        {
          "C1": "some info",
          "C2": someinfo",
          "C3": {
            "D1": "some info",
            "D2": [
              "cat",
              "dog"
            ],
            "D3": "some info"
          },
          "C4": "some info",
          "C5": "some info"
        },
           {
          "C1": "some info",
          "C2": someinfo",
          "C3": {
            "D1": "some info",
            "D2": [
              "cat",
              "dog"
            ],
            "D3": "some info"
          },
          "C4": "some info",
          "C5": "some info"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

and i want to scan it, and if Values[i].C3.D2 doesn't include "fish", i want to remove Values[i], so i want my  new (after edit) JObject to look like this:

```
       {
    "A": "sr",
    "B": {
      "B1": "some data",
      "B2": "some data,
      "Values": [
        {
          "C1": "some info",
          "C2": someinfo",
          "C3": {
            "D1": "some info",
            "D2": [
              "cat",
              "dog",
              "fish"
            ],
            "D3": "some info"
          },
          "C4": "some info",
          "C5": "some info"
        },
           {
          "C1": "some info",
          "C2": someinfo",
          "C3": {
            "D1": "some info",
            "D2": [
              "cat",
              "fish"
            ],
            "D3": "some info"
          },
          "C4": "some info",
          "C5": "some info"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

what is the best and cleanest way for it?

Comment: Convert your jsons to list of objects, use linq to filter and regenerate from object to jsons.

Comment: how? it is allready an object(JObject).

Answer (score 0):

for sample filter Odd number:

```
public class MyClass{
    public string A{get; set;}
    public List<int> B{get; set;}
 }

string js= "{"A" : "1","B" : [1,2,3,4,5,6]}";

MyClass obj  = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyClass>(js);

obj.B= obj.B.Where(t => t % 2 == 0).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Some messy Linq will do it. Select `Values` into a new object where `D2` contains "fish" then replace `Values` on the original object.

```
string jsondata = @"{ ""A"":""sr"", ""B"": { ""B1"":""some data"", ""B2"":""some data"", ""Values"": [{ ""C1"":""some info"", ""C2"":""someinfo"", ""C3"": { ""D1"":""some info"", ""D2"": [ ""cat"", ""dog"", ""fish"" ], ""D3"":""some info"" }, ""C4"":""some info"", ""C5"":""some info"" }, { ""C1"":""some info"", ""C2"":""someinfo"", ""C3"": { ""D1"":""some info"", ""D2"": [ ""cat"", ""dog"" ], ""D3"":""some info"" }, ""C4"":""some info"", ""C5"":""some info"" }, { ""C1"":""some info"", ""C2"": ""someinfo"", ""C3"": { ""D1"":""some info"", ""D2"": [ ""cat"", ""dog"" ], ""D3"":""some info"" }, ""C4"":""some info"", ""C5"":""some info"" } ] } } ";
JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(jsondata);
var filteredValues = jobj["B"]["Values"].Select(j => j).Where(j => j["C3"]["D2"].ToArray().Contains("fish")); 
jobj["B"]["Values"] = JToken.FromObject(filteredValues);

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jobj));
```